# Categorised Product Search & Store In Database

Tags: google-shopping-api, google-product-search

Here I am looking for an API for product search which can return me following things:

1. Categories of products so that user can click on particular category and search exactly what they want.
2. List of products with some information like title,description,price,url and image etc
3. Finally I want to store product information in my database

I looked at google shopping API but its deprecated. Checked for google commerce search but its not having category thing. One more API I found is https://www.semantics3.com which is good but need to pay. I may missed something in my research and you guys may help me with this, so:

1. Is there any possibility of using google shopping API OR google commerce search?
2. If I go for any paid API then I want to have some suggestions over this, so that I can use best solution.

TIA
Jaya

Comment: Hi Jaya, this is Varun from Semantics3. Drop me a message at varun@semantics3.com. We can work out a custom plan that is affordable for you.

Comment: Thanks Varun, I am working on this with your $9 plan. I'll let you know for further help.